# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[,]' to 'string' when returning to main C#

Tags: c#, arrays, class, 2d, return

YO. I'm a beginner in game development and I'm making a console tictactoe game, I'm trying to pass the board grid from the Board class for my game to main because I want to put the gameboard in it's own class. I made a 2D array to hold the characters of the board but I'm having trouble returning it, the error is "cannot implicitly convert type 'string[,]' to 'string'.

```
private int maxRow = 3;
private int maxColumn = 3;
private string[,] boardGrid = new string[3, 3]; //create the game board grid

//Initialise board method
public string InitBoard () //make an object of the board class, returns a 2d array because the board is essentially a grid
{
     //initialise board
     for (int row = 0; row < maxRow; row++)
     {
          for (int column = 0; column < maxColumn; column++)
          {
               boardGrid [row, column] = ".";
          }
     }
     return boardGrid; //<---[The problem happens here!]
}
```

This is the code for the main class.

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    Board ticTacToeBoard = new Board ();
    ticTacToeBoard = ticTacToeBoard.InitBoard ();
    ticTacToeBoard.DisplayBoard (ticTacToeBoard);
}
```

I couldn't find any other question on this but if there is one then feel free to point me to it. Cheers!

Comment: Your InitBoard should return a string[,] not a string and, in the main method, you expect a Board instance not a string[,] returned by InitBoard. Please show the Board class code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few problems here:

- You shouldn't generally need to call a separate method to initialize an object after construction. Put the initialization in the constructor
- You're trying to return a `string[,]` from a method declared to return `string`. That's not going to work
- You're trying to assign a value of `string` to a variable of type `Board`. That's not going to work
- You're passing the state within an object back into a method called on the same object. That's pointless.

Your main method *should* be as simple as:

```
Board ticTacToeBoard = new Board();
ticTacToeBoard.DisplayBoard();
```

Put all the initialization logic into your constructor, and make your `DisplayBoard` method use the variable within the object itself.

I'd also be tempted to make `maxRow` and `maxColumn` constants, *or* make them parameters in the constructor.

Comment: Thankyou Jon, that helped me solve all my issues, I can get on with making this game now, cheers!